# How to create Tinder like edit profile

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-asynctask, tinder

I wanted to create Tinder like edit profile section

**1)** I am having issue in creating dynamic Grids(2 Grid in advance) to users which automatically appears as soon as user fill second last grid.

**2)** Show thumbnail to users in gridview by storing in SD card or Wait for getting image link from server after uploading ?

**3)** How to Show '+' Button on blank grid and 'x' on grid with pictures?

**4)** How to send multiple images to server via AsyncTask as soon as user press Save or Done button

**5)** How to show blank grids with '+' sign?

[image]

Comment: btw use Retrofit and Picasso for Networking, much simpler..

Comment: i will use Picasso when i get image link from server but first i need to get image in grid

Comment: is there any library that will fulfill this view?